# Reactive programming how to do decision making

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am new to reactive programming. To get my hands on i am trying to build a simple rest api but with request validation and db operations.

here are my steps i would like to do.

1. validate incoming request parameter
2. after verified keep continue chain and fetch from db

   - If user not exists in db return some error response
   - If user exists return success response with user name

note: request and response represented by classes (UserRequest and UserResponse).
DB = Mongo using reactive drivers.

I have done the validation work but now i am confuse how to continue and what is the proper way in reactive programming.

```
@Component
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository; // repo has find by id method which returns Mono<User>

    public Mono<ServerResponse> handleUserRequest(ServerRequest serverRequest) {

        Mono<UserRequest> request = validateRequest(serverRequest);
        
        // what should i do here like now i would like to fetch user from db

        return ServerResponse.ok().body("Welcome", String.class);
        // how would i return "Welcome <username>";
    }

    private Mono<UserRequest> validateRequest(ServerRequest request) {

        Mono<UserRequest> userRequest = Mono.just(new UserRequest());

        Mono<UserRequest> validateUser = userRequest
                .map(req -> { //validate id
                    Optional<String> userid = request.queryParam("userid");

                    if (user.isPresent() && ObjectId.isValid(userid.get())) {
                        return req.setUserid(userid.get());
                    }

                    throw new RequestEntityValidationException("Invalid user");
                });


        return validateUser;
    }
}
```

Also is there any side by side tutorial like which show general code snippets in imperative then in reactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea of reactive programming is to work with flow chain all the time.
According to the db data fetching you can take data with `userRepository.findUserById(id)` or similar to this. As a result you will receive `Mono<User>` that can have value or not - then it is an empty Mono.

To handle that case I would suggest code that in this way:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> handleUserRequest(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    return validateRequest(serverRequest)
            .flatMap(userRequest -> userRepository.findUserById(userRequest.getUserId())
                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Not found")))
            )
            .flatMap(user -> ServerResponse.ok().body("Welcome " + user.getUsername(), String.class));
}
```

You can adjust your `validateRequest` method to be more in functional way (without `isPresent` check):

```
private Mono<UserRequest> validateRequest(ServerRequest request) {
    return Mono.just(request)
            .map(req -> request.queryParam("userId")
                    .map(UserRequest::new)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Invalid user"))
            );
}
```

Comment: in this code in your answer .flatMap(userRequest what if i use map instead of flat map?

Comment: You will receive Mono<Mono<UserRequest>>

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in way when using functional reactive HTTP endpoints but you might try https://github.com/making/yavi

You can use `@Valid` for Spring Webflux HTTP `@Controller`